# .htaccess переадресации и прочие штуки с адресной строкой

Tags: .htaccess

Здраститя. Как  сделать вот так вот? - набираю в адресной строке адрес сайта (сайт.ру), и загружается страница (сайт.ру/логин.пхп, а не сайт.ру). Я логинюсь и меня выбрасывает на адрес - сайт.ру. Это в .htaccess вроде делается, но я не знаю как. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: наберите в гугле апач редирект .htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Точно не помню, но вроде так:

```
RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ !^www.example.com/login.php [L,R=301]
```

а вообще [вот тут](http://www.htaccessredirect.net/) конструктор правил редиректа в .htaccess

Comment: Перед login.php в адресной строке добавляется - u121540061/public_html/!^ а после этого - www.example.com/login.php
За ссылку благодарствую.

Answer (score 1):

В гугле выскакивает много результатов. 
Кажется можно так

```
RedirectPermanent / http://test1.ru/login.php
```

**UPD** Мы не правильно поняли наверно, точнее не правильно прочитали. Вам нужно что бы вас если вы не вошли перекидывало на login.php. На login.php вы входите.  И вас перекидывает на index.php.

Есть такой вариант.
Если у вас данные после авторизации например сохраняются в ссесию (например $_SESSION['id'] и $_SESSION['login']).
то можно в индекс
засунуть вот такую чтучку

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['id']) or empty($_SESSION['login']){
header("Location: http://test1.ru/login.php");
}
?>
```

А в логин нужно посли регистрации просто перекинуть на index.php (ну на главную)

Comment: Тоже самое. Перед login.php в адресной строке добавляется - u121540061/public_html/!^ а после этого - www.example.com/login.php